# Prove that infinite dihedral group is isomorphic to $G=\langle a,b|a^2=b^2=1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here the infinite dihedral group is defined as $D=\langle r,s|r^s=r^{-1},s^2=1\rangle$.

I identified that $rs=sr^{-1}=s^{-1}r^{-1}=(rs)^{-1}$, hence $|rs|=|s|=2$. And then I defined a map $\sigma:\{r,s\} \rightarrow G$ by sending $rs$ to $a$ and $s$ to $b$, and extend $\sigma$ to homomorphism $\overline{\sigma}: F(rs,s)\rightarrow G$ where $F(rs,s)$ is a free group. And by Von Dyck's theorem I obtain a surjective homomorphism mapping $D$ to $G$, and show that it is also injective.

My question is, is $\{rs,s\}$ a free basis for $F(r,s)$? Does my method work?

Comment: What does it mean by $r^s=r^{-1}$?

Comment: $r^s=s^{-1}rs=r^{-1}$

Comment: Perhaps you should try going the other way around, definikg $G\to D$, $a\to rs$, $b\to s$. Since $rs$ and $s$ are of order $2$, this is well defined (universal property of free groups). Next you can show that this is injective and surjective. For surjectivity, notice that $r= rs s^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm guessing that $\{rs,s\}$ is a free basis, to show this you need to show that for $u=rs$, $v=s$ any product, for example, like $u^{i_1}v^{i_1}\cdots u^{i_n}v^{i_n}$ doesn't reduce to identity (empty string). I think you can show this by counting how many $r$'s are in there after cancelling, i.e. in particular there are more than $0$ of them so they are not identity.

Comment: See Theorem 4.4 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf.